# JSON - Parse invalid terminated string using jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have below json retrieving from third party API.

```
{ 'id': 1, 'name': "user1", 'address': "IN", }
```

How i can parse this with jackson mapper. I am getting below exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

My code like follow:

```
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
    objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_MISSING_VALUES, true);
    objectMapper.readTree("{ 'id': 1, 'name': \"user1\", 'address': \"IN\", }");
```

Note: i dont want to replace last comma, i want to know is there any option to tee jackson to execlude that?

Comment: why do not you want to remove the last comma. Could you explain it?

Comment: `objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA, true);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/118
just add:

```
JsonParser.ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA
```

see more info:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/323

Comment: The field appears to have moved to an enum in newer versions : https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html#ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA

Answer (score 0):

In jackson 2.11+, it's configured slightly differently:

```
var mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
    .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA)
    .build();
```